# Change data greater than a given date to NULL in one column. Getting key error

Tags: sql, null, key

I have a column filled with dates, some of which are duplicates, and I want to change all the ones greater than 2012-05-28 to NULL.  Here is the statement I'm using:

```
UPDATE my_data SET date_firstnewtumor=NULL
WHERE date_firstnewtumor>2012-05-28;
```

However, MySQL Workbench is giving me this error message: "...you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a key column."

I then tried the above code in MySQL Command Line Client and it changed the entire column date_firstnewtumor to NULL.

I've looked at examples of code online and I could swear their WHERE statement was similar to mine.  What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your advice!

Comment: date value should be in single quotes: '2012-05-28'. also add an index to date_firstnewtumor column if you do not already have one on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll just want to specify the [date literal](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html) correctly:

```
WHERE date_firstnewtumor > '2012-05-28';
```

Or simply:

```
WHERE date_firstnewtumor > 20120528;
```

Comment: This works.  I had tried this earlier in MySQL Workbench and it still gave the error message, but I just tried it in Command Line and it worked.  Thanks!